Now when vs now that and the difference between them

Now when you are working I will help

Correct, we can use "now when" becuase the action is really happening right now.

Now when you work I will help you

Wrong, if we mean a repeated event that is not happening right now, instead we should use "now that".
Is my understanding correct?

You are entirely wrong. Now when is not particularly idiomatic. Now that you work/are working, I will help you means I am willing to help now because you have started working.

These sentences don't really make sense without more context. The only context that I could imagine fixing @KateBunting's objections would be if "now" means "it hasn't been this way in the past, but something has just changed, and now it's true." Voting to close as lacking context and clarity; please edit to tell more about where you found these sentences or what kind of situation you're trying to address.

"Now when" would convey the same meaning or nobody rely uses that words but "now that"?

You can also use a parenthetical, but we usually use "while": Now, while you're working, I will help.

@Barmar what would be the difference between "now, while you are working" and "now, while you work"?

There's not much difference. But since working is an ongoing activity, we usually use the continuous tense.

@Barmar wouldn't present simple imply a habit?

@thomas Not when used with "when", "if", etc.. "When you text me I'll respond."

Consider:

Now when you apply for a medical license, the state requires a notarized letter from the university that conferred your medical degree.
Now that you have a medical license, you can start practicing medicine.

Now when introduces a scenario.
Now that introduces a fact.
The clause headed by when states the scenario.
The clause headed by that declares the fact.

What about "now while"?

now while introduces a fact. The fact is temporary.    "Now while I have you on the phone, let's go over the contract changes."    "Now while shirts are 25% off, I am going to buy a few."
